# How to get resource as byte array in c#?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I added image to my c# project from Project settings -> Resources
How can i get this image at runtime?
I trying this:

```
public byte[] GetResource(string ResourceName)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

    // list all resources in assembly - for test
    string[] names = asm.GetManifestResourceNames(); //even here my TestImg.png is not presented

    System.IO.Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceName); //this return null of course

    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    return data;
}
```

I call this function this way:

```
byte[] data = GetResource("TestImg.png");
```

But I see my image in Resources folder in project explorer.
[image]

Could anyone tell what's wrong there?
[image]

Comment: Why do you cast `stream.Length` to an `int`? It already is an `int`. `.LongLength` returns a `long`.

Comment: I don't know how, but for me Stream.Length is **long**

Comment: It's worked for me with use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the file `TestImg.png` as an "Embedded Resource." The resource name would then be `Resources/TestImg.png`.

Comment: TestImg.png is not even presented in asm.GetManifestResourceNames(); What the difference then if changing name of resource I search for? And anyway, i tried, no luck

Comment: Anyways, can you tell us what `asm.GetManifestResourceNames` returns? That would help.

Comment: Where I can set TestImg.png as embedded resource? I don't see this in Project settings -> Resources

Comment: @Kosmos [Right-click either the text file or the bitmap, and then select **Properties**. In the **Properties** dialog box, locate the **Build Action** property. By default, this property is set to **Content**. Click the property and change the **Build Action** property to **Embedded Resource**.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

Comment: Thank you, finally in can be seen in **names**. To sad, the name is kinda weird - VLab_1_new.Resources.TestImg.png

Answer (score 2):

You can access the image with `Properties.Resources.TestImg`.

Comment: wow, this is so easy and really works :O thank you. Too sad it not at runtime

Comment: What I want is to show this image in WebBrowser by using data protocol http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is ok, but it at design time only... The web page may require any other name of image

Comment: Visual Studio by default causes the image resource to be returned as `Bitmap` rather than as a byte array. See my response.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
    var info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    info.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
```

In additional, if you want to save the image to your drive:

```
    var b =
    new Bitmap(namespace.Properties.Resources.image_resouce_name);
    b.Save("FILE LOCATION");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the Resources.resx file and change:

```
  <data name="ResourceKey" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\Image.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

to (replace the type and assembly definition after the file name):

```
  <data name="ResourceKey" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\Image.jpg;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </data>
```

Regenerate the .Designer.cs file, such as by opening the resources (.resx file) in the designer and changing its access type to internal and then back to public (or vice versa). Now you can access the image as byte array using `Properties.Resources.ResourceKey`. I don't know if this can be done without manually editing the resource file.